# CHEF- Having a hard time figuring out how SUDO COOKBOOK works

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I was trying to add the `%wheel` group to the `sudoers` file via chef.
Unfortunately i'm having an hard time to figure out how this cookbook works. The [readme](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/sudo#readme) doesn't sound very clear to me.

What i have done:

- Added

  ```rb
  depends          'sudo'
  ```

  to the metadata file of my recipe
- Added the following line at the end of the recipe

  ```rb
  node.default['authorization']['sudo']['groups'] = ['wheel']
  ```

What happens (the line gets completely ignored):

```rb
Recipe: create-user::default
  * yum_package[sudo] action install[2016-06-09T19:01:12+01:00] INFO: Processing yum_package[sudo] action install (create-user::default line 9)
 (up to date)
  * user[edgarsan] action create[2016-06-09T19:01:13+01:00] INFO: Processing user[edgarsan] action create (create-user::default line 14)
 (up to date)
  * group[wheel] action modify[2016-06-09T19:01:13+01:00] INFO: Processing group[wheel] action modify (create-user::default line 21)
 (up to date)
  * user[banana] action create[2016-06-09T19:01:13+01:00] INFO: Processing user[banana] action create (create-user::default line 14)
 (up to date)
  * group[wheel] action modify[2016-06-09T19:01:13+01:00] INFO: Processing group[wheel] action modify (create-user::default line 21)
 (up to date)
[2016-06-09T19:01:13+01:00] INFO: Chef Run complete in 3.322762038 seconds
```

I'm missing something but i'm not finding out what it is from the documentation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also execute the default recipe by adding the following line to your recipe:

```rb
include_recipe "sudo"
```

This will use this attribute [here](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/sudo/blob/22bb7a3138fb1c36af5ac3227c01b1289635e65e/recipes/default.rb#L47):

```rb
template "#{prefix}/sudoers" do
  # <snip>
  variables(
    sudoers_groups: node['authorization']['sudo']['groups'],
    # <snip>
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

With `include_recipe "sudo"` i was getting the following error, thats the reason why i removed the statement in the first place. Fortunately @StephenKing put me back on track... and showed me that the statement was actually there for a reason :)

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[/sudoers]'
================================================================================

    Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError
    ------------------------------------
    undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

...
    Template Context:
    -----------------
    on line #4
      2: # Do NOT modify this file directly.
      3: 
      4: <% @sudoers_defaults.each do |defaults| -%>
      5: Defaults      <%= defaults %>
      6: <% end -%>
...
```

i.e. defaults were not passing to the sudo recipe. The solution was to swap `node.default['authorization']['sudo']['groups'] = ['wheel']` in **recipes/default.rb** by `default['authorization']['sudo']['groups'] = ['wheel']` in **attributes/default.rb**

Now everything works as expected